# What is the origin of Sheik's design in Super Smash Bros. Ultimate?

Tags: video-games, the-legend-of-zelda

In *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate*, the character of Sheik seems to be sporting a new design that matches neither *Ocarina of Time* nor *Hyrule Warriors*.

What (if any) prior appearance is this version based on? If no previous media has sported this design, what is the new design based upon?

[image: Sheik in the new costume design.]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a design based on one of the costumes in *Breath of the Wild*. From the [official Super Smash Bros blog](https://www.smashbros.com/en_US/blog/index.html?category=cat02_fighter_16):

> Now Sheik joins the battle wearing the Sheikah costume from The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild.

Answer (score -2):

Like said, Sheik is just wearing items you can collect in Zelda Breath of the Wild. The outfit is a clothing item you can buy in Kakariko Village, and the headpiece is an item you can get from the Sheik amiibo.